# how to disable journaling on xfs filesystem

Tags: linux, xfs, diskmanagement

How do I disable journaling on  xfs file system. I tried tune2fs to disable, it didnt help.

Does xfs has different tools/procedure to do so ?

```
tune2fs -o journal_data_writeback  /dev/mapper/fedora00-root
```

Comment: XFS is a journal filesystem, I don't think you can disable this feature.  Anyway why would you want to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`tune2fs`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tune2fs) is management tool for the EXT2, EXT3 and EXT4 file systems, not for the XFS filesystem.

Second [XFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFS) is, as @mdpc mentioned, designed as a journaled filesystem and you can't disable journaling, although some of the journal paramaters are tuneable and you can choose to use an external device as the place for the journal (i.e. a fast SSD) instead of the internal one to improve performance by using a separate IO path.

Chack the manual pages for [mkfs.xfs](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.xfs), [xfs](http://linux.die.net/man/5/xfs), [xfs_admin](http://linux.die.net/man/8/xfs_admin) and [xfs_db](http://linux.die.net/man/8/xfs_db) to name a few.

Comment: You should hope that the tune2fs execution did not write something to the XFS filesystem that corrupted it!